# Keep getting NoMethodError in Chapters#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have books, with chapters nested underneath, with questions for each chapter nested within the chapters, and comments nested in the questions.

When I click on new chapter on the books page how do I get it to save to the book its associated with, and how do I get the books#show page to loop through all the chapter titles (with links to each chapters show page).

This is the error: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass. Referring to this file: Users/bardiap/saasapp/app/views/books/show.html.erb

```
<div class="homepage">

<h1><%= @book.title %></h1>

<%= link_to 'New chapter', new_book_chapter_path(@book, @chapter) %>

<% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
            <h3><%= link_to chapter.title, chapter %></h3>
        <% end %>

<p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(@book) %> |
<%= link_to 'Destroy', book_path(@book),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', books_path %> |
</p>

</div>
```

Here is my books and chapters controllers:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @chapters = Chapter.where(book_id: @book.id).order("created_at ASC")
  end

  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end

  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @book =  Book.new(book_params)

    if @book.save
      redirect_to @book
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])

    if @book.update(book_params)
      redirect_to @book
    else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book.destroy

    redirect_to books_path
  end

  private
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title,:text,:author)
    end
  end
```

Chapter

```
def show
    @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
    @questions = question.where(chapter_id: @chapter.id).order("created_at ASC")
  end

  def index
    @chapters = Chapter.all
  end

  def new
    @chapter = Chapter.new
  end

  def edit
    @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @chapter = Chapter.new(chapter_params)

    if @chapter.save
      render 'books/show'
    else
      render 'books/show'
    end
  end

  def update
    @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])

    if @chapter.update(chapter_params)
      redirect_to @chapter
    else
      render 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
    @chapter.destroy

    redirect_to chapters_path
  end

  private
    def chapter_params
      params.require(:chapter).permit(:title, :text)
    end
  end
```

Here are the models and routes

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chapters
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length:{minimum: 5}
end

class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions
  belongs_to :book
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length:{minimum: 5}
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'terms', to: 'pages#terms'
  get 'privacy', to: 'pages#privacy'

  resources :contacts, only: :create
  resources :podcasts
  resources :books do
    resources :chapters, shallow: true
  end
  resources :chapters do
    resources :questions, shallow: true
  end
  resources :questions do
    resources :comments, module: :questions, shallow: true
  end
  resources :users do
    resource :profile
    resources :comments
  end
  get 'contact-us', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'new_contact'
  get 'podcast', to: 'pages#podcast'
  resources :essays do
    resources :comments, module: :essays, shallow: true
  end
end
```

And views:

chapters/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@book, @chapter] do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

chapters/index.html.erb

```
<div class="homepage">



  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab">
    <i class="material-icons"><%= link_to "add", new_chapter_path%></i>
  </button>

<div class="mdl-grid">
<% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <div class="demo-card-event mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h4>
          <%=chapter.title%>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
          <%=link_to 'VIEW BOOK',chapter_path(chapter), class: "mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"%>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <i class="material-icons">chapter</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>

<% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_chapter_path(chapter) %> |
<%= link_to 'Destroy', chapter_path(chapter),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>

<br><br><br><br><br>

</div>
```

chapters/show.html.erb

```
<div class="homepage">


<h3><%= @chapter.title %></h3>
<h5><%= @chapter.text %></h5>



<p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(@book) %> |
<%= link_to 'Destroy', book_path(@book),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', books_path %> |
</p>

</div>
```

Where am I going wrong, and is there other things I can do to make my code work better.

Comment: It is usually helpful if you include your actual stack trace for the error so that we can see exactly what is going on. Also, to make your question more readable, I suggest you edit out all of the unnecessary code (e.g., we don't need to see *every* `BooksController` action, your `ChapterController` code is irrelevant, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

To create a new Chapter in a Book, in books/show:

```
<%= link_to 'New chapter', new_book_chapter_path(@book) %>
```

(No need to pass the chapter, as it will be created). Then, in ChaptersController#new:

```
def new
  @book = Book.find_by(id: params[:book_id]
  if @book
    @chapter = @book.chapters.build
  end
end
```

You can also change BooksController#show

```
def show
  @book = Book.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if @book
    @chapters = @book.chapters.order("created_at ASC")
  end
end
```

Comment: `find` can raise exceptions. `find_by(id: ...)` won't, and it's also more verbose for no reason.

Comment: The reason I prefer `find` is you can `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` to control the flow instead of an `if` or you can have a singular `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` handler for the whole controller.